# rlang Expressions in List as Args to Function

Tags: r, metaprogramming, rlang, tidymodels, r-recipes

I'm trying to parse user input as arguments to a function call (within an expression). It seems like I'm close but !!! is wrapping my arguments in parenthesis which is not working. I'm trying to recreate the following with user inputs:

```
recipe(mpg ~ cyl + hp + wt + disp, data = mtcars) %>% 
  step_log(disp, base = 10, offset = 0) %>% 
  prep()
```

```
library(rlang)
library(tidymodels)

user_dv <- "mpg"
user_idv <- c("cyl", "hp", "wt", "disp")

user_step <- "log"
user_selector <- "disp"
user_args <- "base = 10, offset = 0"

formula <- as.formula(paste(user_dv, paste(user_idv, collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ "))

rcp <- expr(recipe(!!formula,data = mtcars))

add_step <- function(x, step, selector, args){
  f <- parse_expr(paste0("step_", step))
  vars <- ensym(user_selector)
  
  args <- args %>% 
    str_replace(",", ";") %>% 
    parse_exprs()

  step_expr <- call2(f, vars, !!!args)
  
  expr(!!x %>% !!step_expr)
  
}

rcp %>% 
  add_step(user_step, user_selector, user_args) %>% 
  eval() %>% 
  prep()
```

My expression ends up looking like this:

```
recipe(mpg ~ cyl + hp + wt + disp, data = mtcars) %>% 
      step_log(disp, (base = 10), (offset = 0))
```

Which does not prep()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `parse_exprs()`, you end up with assignment expressions stored in an unnamed list:

```
# [[1]]
# base = 10
#
# [[2]]
# offset = 0
```

while, to get the effect you want with `!!!`, they need to be values in a named list:

```
# $base
# [1] 10
#
# $offset
# [1] 0
```

With that said, I suggest "forwarding the dots" instead, because it leads to a simpler and more flexible implementation:

```
add_step <- function(x, step, selector, ...){
  f <- parse_expr(paste0("step_", step))
  vars <- sym(selector)
  step_expr <- call2(f, vars, ...)      # <---- forwarding the dots here

  expr(!!x %>% !!step_expr)
}
```

The user can now simply provide the desired arguments directly to `add_step()`:

```
rcp %>% add_step(user_step, user_selector, base=10, offset=0)

# recipe(mpg ~ cyl + hp + wt + disp, data = mtcars) %>% 
#    step_log(disp, base = 10, offset = 0)
```

OR store them in a list and use `!!!` on **your** function:

```
user_args <- list(base = 10, offset=0)
rcp %>% add_step(user_step, user_selector, !!!user_args)
```

Comment: That makes sense, I appreciate it. I'm building this into a shiny app which is why my user inputs are in a less than ideal format but I think asking for specific input and formatting it into a named list is going to make more sense in the long run anyway.